# Is there a way to dull/fade the coloring of marks in Altair?

Tags: altair

I have the following DataFrame (only a part of it is shown):

[image]

I use it to generate the following plot in Altair. I generated this plot based on a modification of the code suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71059865/is-there-a-way-to-transform-a-nominal-dataframe-into-a-bubble-plot-in-altair/71065980#71065980).

[image]

However, due to the fact that each of my Y labels has a different number of associated data points, the only way I could make the plot appear as desired was by using [np.resize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) to repeat values. This works almost perfectly, but leads to the unfortunate issue that some of the marks in the plot appear darker than others, which can be misleading because it does not actually relate to the data in any way. Is there any way to get around this in Altair?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking about the opacity of the marks, which defaults to semi-transparent. You can adjust this with the `opacity` argument to `mark_point()`; for example:

```py
alt.Chart(data).mark_point(opacity=1)
```